# How to have Logstash shipper to grab a value from a local file and passed to indexer ?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I have a logstash project that in general is of this architecture:

" 
Several logstash Shippers ==> Redis ==> Logstash Indexer ==> ES
".

For each individual Shipper, it needs to grab an ID VALUE from a local file, and have it passed to the Logstash Indexer, that will be used as its unique "INDEX" String. But I don't know how this can be done. Two Quesions here:

a) how this value may be grabbed from a file ?

b) how this value may be passed from shipper to the indexer ?

I know how it works if this string is part of the "path" value, but if it was from a file, I am still clueless.  Anyone has any clue for that ?

John.

Comment: What is this ID value? Is it constant for each shipper? If not, when or why will it change? There may be much simpler ways to achieve your goals.

Comment: You could modify the startup script to retrieve the string from the file and add it to your path.